# Ion exchange resins

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solutions, coordination-compounds

My problem is explained quite easily: I have no experience with ion exchange resins but I would like to test something out in order to exchange my sulfate ions in solution for nitrate (can also be perchlorate or tetrafluoroborate or something similar). Has anybody worked with such resins? Is there anything available on the market?

EDIT: I have seen that most resins work in water, but my compound is soluble in DCM, MeOH, EtOH and also chloroform, less so in acetonitrile, so I would need something that in the best case works in one of those solvents.

Comment: How big and how polar is your compound? You can load an anion exchange resin with hydroxide and then remove all anions in your solution, replacing them with hydroxide. Not sure if you could load it with nitrate instead.

Comment: @KarstenTheis pretty big (like 8Å across, but its a bit bent) and quite unpolar due to an extended pi-system